# Failed to find input Node 'image_tensor' in tensorflow android

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

i trained object detection model by tensorflow and i manage to get .tflite file from it too but when i run my model in android sample it say 
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to find input Node 'image_tensor'
after that i tried to use some python scripts which gives me output and input of my graph and they says that

output name = 
num_detections

Input name = 
12345678910111image_tensor

i put this input name too and again it gives me same error as before

Answer (score 0):

i solve the problem by doing this

```
boolean TF_OD_API_IS_QUANTIZED = false;
```

from DetectorActivity